# JDI apply class filters for multiple classes

Tags: java, regex, jdi, jpda

I am creating a `MethodEntryRequest`, and I want to apply this request to only methods of two class patterns for ex:- `"java.*"` and `"sun.*"`. For that I had written following code.

```
MethodEntryRequest menr = mgr.createMethodEntryRequest();
menr.setSuspendPolicy(EventRequest.SUSPEND_ALL);
menr.addClassFilter("java.*|sun.*");
```

The problem with above code is it disables all method events. But if I apply only one class pattern method it is working fine. I tried escaping `"|"` with `"\\\\|"` but it did not work. So I want to know how to apply class filter for more than one class pattern ?

Comment: Your answer did not work. I did not understand what you meant by examples and acceptables.

Comment: I tried "(java).*" instead of "java.*" and found out both are not equal '()' is causing some problem

Comment: Oops! As documented: _Regular expressions are limited to exact matches and patterns that begin with `'*'` or end with `'*'`; for example, `"*.Foo"` or `"java.*"`._

Comment: But these all are ending with *

Comment: No, they work alone, but they dont work combined.

Comment: Can you try `(java|sun).*`?

Comment: Yeah @bulbus I tried but its not working, it filters all classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is something wrong and normal java regex are not working. So I solved my problem by making two MethodEntryRequests one for "sun.*" and one for "java.*". But this is not the best answer as for each class pattern there would be one MethodEntryRequest.